# Is this powershell script appropriately using the Get-ADUser command to filter with a txt file?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Here is the command I have so far.

```
$List = Get-Content c:\userlist.txt
$Users = @()

foreach ($Item in $List)
{
    $Users += Get-ADUser -Filter {samAccountName -like "*$Item*"}
}

$Users | Select-Object samAccountName,Surname
```

What I want to do is use PowerShell and take a list of users to pull information such as login IPs, client host names, and login successes/failures from AD. Is this a good command to start with? The script isn't how I would like it just yet as I haven't configured it to my liking so it's just a base idea I have yet to edit.

Comment: Performance related: read and follow [Appending to arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster#appending-to-arrays). When the `+=` operator is used, it's actually destroying the array and creating a new one.

Comment: Are you looking to gather this for all IDs or only certain ones?  If the latter, then this is fine.  As an alternative use a csv file and import-csv.  That way, you could specify the properties you plan to gather (as empty columns), update them in the foreach loop then export them at the end

Comment: Active Directory does not natively store the authentication info you are looking for. The best you can get from an AD user object is the last logon timestamp. The data you want is found by analyzing Kerberos event logs on the domain controllers.